# How to set gid and uid in os.FileMode in golang?

Tags: file, go, permissions, userid

I want to set the uid and gid on files that are created by our golang application. It looks like the right place is use the [os.FileMode](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#FileMode). I am looking for an example of setting the permissions and uid and gid all in one step.

Setting the permissions looks pretty straightforward:

```
os.FileMode(hdr.Mode&0777)
```

But I am not sure how to also set the uid/gid on FileMode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what do you mean by one step, I use following method to set uid & gid

func Chown(path string, uid int, gid int)

https://golang.org/pkg/syscall/#Chown

Comment: I saw `ModeSetuid  // u: setuid` and `ModeSetgid  // g: setgid` in the FileMode documentation and I was wondering if there was a way to mask the uid and gid in the resulting FileMode int.

Comment: @MattBruzek Be careful, those mode bits mean something else: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19683-01/816-4883/secfile-69/index.html